# How to ignore files with Capistrano 3 without copy_exlude

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

In Capistrano 2 it was possible to exclude certain files that live in the Git repository with copy_exclude:

```
set :copy_exclude, %w{.git .DS_Store web concept config lib}
```

This isn't possible anymore in Capistrano 3. How can I exclude certain files that I want in my Git repository but not necessarily on my server?

Answer (score 5):

The way to achieve this is to add a `.gitattributes` to the root of your repo. It works very similar to `.gitignore`. Just add the paths to all the files you want in your repository but not on your staging / production server followed by `export-ignore` and commit+push the changes.

Sample `.gitattributes` file:

```
# Folders
/config export-ignore
/lib export-ignore

# Files
license.txt export-ignore
readme.html export-ignore
```

Then deploy like usual. More info [here](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/excluding-files-from-git-archive/)